# Error Conflict between fourienc package with amsmath pakage

Tags: color, amsmath, fourier, amsfonts

I type a below document using fourienc package and amsmath package

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,txfonts,ulem}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm] {geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
 %\ding{168} % club
 %\ding{169} % diamond
 %\ding{170} % heart
 %\ding{171} % spade
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{blue}}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{cyan}} 
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \Huge{\color{red}\textbf{THÔNG BÁO}}\\
 \large{
 \color{blue}\textbf{
 Chiêu sinh lớp bồi dưỡng kiến thức môn Toán trong hè \\ các lớp $\pmb{10}$, $\pmb{11}$, $\pmb{12}$
 }
 }
\end{center}
\section{Đối tượng}
 %Học sinh có nhu cầu bổ sung kiến thức từ cơ bản đến nâng cao để chuẩn bị cho năm học 2017 - 2018
 $$x^2-3x+2=0$$
\section{Thời gian, địa điểm}
\section{Nội dung học tập}
\section{Học phí}
\section{Nội quy lớp học}
\large\ding{170}
\end{document}
```

When I build file then I get error.
Please help me!

Comment: Your code compiles fine here. Try replacing the deprecated `txfonts` by `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. Also, since you load `xcolor` you don't need to load `color`. You should *always* load `xcolor` instead of `color`.

Comment: What is the error?